# grep and/or gather data confusion

Tags: r

This question is pretty straight forward, but difficult for me to achieve.

I have asked many questions on this website about transposing, stacking, and re-arranging data in all sorts of ways, and continue to adapt all these codes from peoples' responses for various applications.  However I have come across an example I am not quite sure how to solve.

I have a dataframe (df) with different names of bacterial species in the header, and values for each bacteria found below each species.

I would like to transpose my dataframe below (df), add a column called "species", and a second column called "value", and fill them in respectively.

On certain days, several species were present on the same day, meaning in the final dataset, I should have "days" repeated several times if there are multiple data points from that day. (see sample_finished_data)

```
    df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/Myhctf7b", header=T, sep="\t")
```

Here is an example of what I would like to have done:

```
    sample_finished_tabled <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/5vHwA5ar",header = T,sep = "\t")
```

I can imagine this is something that I would use grep() or gather() but I would need help building the code.

Thank you as always

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `gather`

```
tidyr::gather(df, species, value, -(1:5), na.rm = TRUE) 

#           ID antibiotic day treatment Agarplate                    species value
#1  Te100.1_d0         Te   0   Te100.1     Tryso    Achromobacter.insolitus   1.0
#2  Te100.1_d0         Te   1   Te100.1       BHI    Achromobacter.insolitus   2.4
#4  Te100.1_d0         Te   3   Te100.1     MRS30    Achromobacter.insolitus   3.0
#5  Te100.1_d0         Te   4   Te100.1       Sab    Achromobacter.insolitus   6.0
#7  Te100.2_d0         Te   6   Te100.2       BHI    Achromobacter.insolitus   7.0
#20 Te100.1_d0         Te   3   Te100.1     MRS30        Acidovorax.defluvii   1.0
#22 Te100.2_d0         Te   5   Te100.2     Tryso        Acidovorax.defluvii   6.0
#30 Te100.2_d0         Te   5   Te100.2     Tryso     Acidovorax.delafieldii   6.0
#31 Te100.2_d0         Te   6   Te100.2       BHI     Acidovorax.delafieldii   7.0
#35 Te100.1_d0         Te   2   Te100.1      Blut Acinetobacter.haemolyticus   5.0
#42 Te100.1_d0         Te   1   Te100.1       BHI    Acinetobacter.johnsonii   2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = 1:5, variable.name = "species", na.rm = TRUE)
#           ID antibiotic day treatment Agarplate                    species value
# 1: Te100.1_d0         Te   0   Te100.1     Tryso    Achromobacter.insolitus   1.0
# 2: Te100.1_d0         Te   1   Te100.1       BHI    Achromobacter.insolitus   2.4
# 3: Te100.1_d0         Te   3   Te100.1     MRS30    Achromobacter.insolitus   3.0
# 4: Te100.1_d0         Te   4   Te100.1       Sab    Achromobacter.insolitus   6.0
# 5: Te100.2_d0         Te   6   Te100.2       BHI    Achromobacter.insolitus   7.0
# 6: Te100.1_d0         Te   3   Te100.1     MRS30        Acidovorax.defluvii   1.0
# 7: Te100.2_d0         Te   5   Te100.2     Tryso        Acidovorax.defluvii   6.0
# 8: Te100.2_d0         Te   5   Te100.2     Tryso     Acidovorax.delafieldii   6.0
# 9: Te100.2_d0         Te   6   Te100.2       BHI     Acidovorax.delafieldii   7.0
#10: Te100.1_d0         Te   2   Te100.1      Blut Acinetobacter.haemolyticus   5.0
#11: Te100.1_d0         Te   1   Te100.1       BHI    Acinetobacter.johnsonii   2.0
```

NOTE: There are many dupes for this

Comment: may I ask you where the variable name "value" is integrated in your code?

Comment: @Andy  `melt`, does automatically by creating two column `variable' and 'value'.  If you check the code, I renamed the 'variable.name' as 'species'